# how to retrieve data from database and show it in calendar?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-calendar

I have retrieved current date data from database but i have a problem in retrieving other date data.on clicking on other date app got stopped.below is my code

CalendarActivity.java

```
public class CalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,CalendarCellDecorator {
    @BindView(R.id.lowerFrame)
FrameLayout frameLayout;

    @BindView(R.id.calendar)
    CalendarPickerView calendarPickerView;

    @BindView(R.id.textqua)
     EditText txtquantity;

    @BindView(R.id.textrate)
    EditText txtrate;

    ContentResolver resolver;
    @BindView(R.id.buttonupdate)
    Button btn;


    @BindView(R.id.textViewquestion)
            TextView txtquestion;

    User user;
    ArrayList<User> users;
    String strDate;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        resolver=getContentResolver();
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        Intent rcv=getIntent();
        users=new ArrayList<>();
        user = (User) rcv.getSerializableExtra("keyuser");


       Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR,2);


       Calendar lastYear= Calendar.getInstance();
       lastYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, -2);
        Date today = new Date();
        calendarPickerView.init(lastYear.getTime(), nextYear.getTime()).withSelectedDate(today).inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.RANGE);
        List<CalendarCellDecorator> decoratorList = new ArrayList<>();
        decoratorList.add(new CalendarActivity());
        calendarPickerView.setDecorators(decoratorList);
        calendarPickerView.setOnDateSelectedListener(new CalendarPickerView.OnDateSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSelected(Date date) {
               // strDate=formatDate(date);
               // Toast.makeText(CalendarActivity.this, formatDate(date), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                queryUsersFromDB();
                strDate=formatDate(date);


                }

            @Override
            public void onDateUnselected(Date date) {

                }
        });

    }


    private String formatDate(Date date) {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        return simpleDateFormat.format(date);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CalendarActivity.this, AllUsersActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }



    private ArrayList<Date> Highlight(){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        String dateInString = user.date;
        Date date=null ;
        try {

            date = sdf.parse(dateInString);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<Date> holidays = new ArrayList<>();
        holidays.add(date);
        return holidays;
    }
    void queryUsersFromDB(){
        String[] projection={Util.COL_QUANTITY,Util.COL_RATE,Util.COL_DATE,Util.COL_TYPE};
        String where=Util.COL_DATE+"="+strDate;
        Cursor cursor=resolver.query(Util.USER_URI,projection,where,null,null);

        if(cursor!=null){

            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                User user=new User();
                user.quantity=cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Util.COL_QUANTITY));
                user.rate=cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Util.COL_RATE));
                user.date=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Util.COL_DATE));
                user.type=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Util.COL_TYPE));

            }
            txtquantity.setText("Quantity: "+String.valueOf(user.quantity));
            txtrate.setText("Rate: "+String.valueOf(user.quantity * user.rate));
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Closing App")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this app?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void decorate(CalendarCellView cellView, Date date) {

            if (date.getDate()<5) {
                cellView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_background);
            } else {
                cellView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
            }

    }

}
```

below is logcat

```
10-18 06:26:39.608 24145-24145/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
    v2
10-18 06:26:39.613 24145-24145/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
10-18 06:26:39.613 24145-24145/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
10-18 06:26:51.143 24145-24145/myapp.com.project E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null
10-18 06:26:51.148 24145-24145/myapp.com.project E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@3fe8153e
10-18 06:27:14.643 24145-24145/myapp.com.project E/SQLiteLog: (1) near ".2018": syntax error
10-18 06:27:14.713 24145-24145/myapp.com.project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: myapp.com.project, PID: 24145
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".2018": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT QUANTITY, RATE, DATE, TYPE FROM User WHERE DATE=18.10.2018
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
        (near ".2018": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT QUANTITY, RATE, DATE, TYPE FROM User WHERE DATE=18.10.2018)
    #################################################################
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1454)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1301)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1172)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1340)
        at myapp.com.project.Provider.MyContentProvider.query(MyContentProvider.java:56)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1007)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:218)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:489)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:433)
        at myapp.com.project.CalendarActivity.queryUsersFromDB(CalendarActivity.java:154)
        at myapp.com.project.CalendarActivity$1.onDateSelected(CalendarActivity.java:106)
        at com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView$CellClickedListener.handleClick(CalendarPickerView.java:497)
        at com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarRowView.onClick(CalendarRowView.java:74)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5246)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21200)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Util.java
```

Comment: Post error log.

Comment: i have posted my logcat.please help .

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is here:

```
    String where=Util.COL_DATE+"="+strDate;
```

This produces

```
    WHERE DATE=18.10.2018
```

which isn’t valid SQL syntax.

I’ve got no experience with SQLite. If using a parameterized query is an option, you should go for it, but I’m afraid I can’t give you the details.

If not, assuming your `date` column is of type `char` or `varchar`, putting the date string in single quotes should work, but is not preferred since it leaves the door open for SQL injection attacks:

```
    String where = Util.COL_DATE + "='" + strDate + "'";
```